# How to add onclick imageview url and how to update url from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, url, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have created an app in which I have added Image view with recyclerview using Firebase storage, so now I want to click on those images with any Url and I want to  fetch url from firebase data and those url open in default browser.

So someone can help me to implement it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add the code that you have used so far and please responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to do for this:

1. When your `file` is `uploading`, just add the `URL` of that file into your `Firebase database` and when the user click on any image, `URL` of that particular `image` should be extracted from whole `database`.
2. Then you have to open your `default browser` and then just use that `URL` (extracted from `Firebase Database`) in the `browser` to view your image in browser.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply to my question but sir I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: @KishanNath Please Add the code you have used so far